# Sqlite3 does not work inside laravel (5.4) Php 7

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, laravel-5.4

I am trying to get Sqlite3 to work on laravel.

In a simple Php file it works great!

```
<?php


$handle = new SQLite3("mydb.db");

?>
```

however inside a function of a laravel controller it fails badly.

```
  <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Cookie\Factory;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Home Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the home - dasboard controller,
    | where you land if you visit the site the first time
    | ror are redirected from the login page.
    |
     */


    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('customauthorize');
    }

    public function Index(Request $request, Factory $cookie)
    {
        $handle = new SQLite3("mydb.db");

        return view('welcome');
    }
}

?>
```

It actually even presents a squiggly line on my Sqlite3 Object.

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\SQLite3' not found
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: You did not import the namespace of the SQLite3.

Comment: thank you for the response, could you tell me what is the namespace, since in my normal php file i did not have to specify it.

Comment: I have no idea :D Is that a custom library or is it something L5.4 ships? Also what's the folder structure of the file where it worked (for example if you tried it in /project/test.php, is it possible that SQLite3 is in the /project folder as well?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your controller, where you see the other use directives, add the following declaration:

```
Use SQLite3;
```

Laravel is driven by PSR-4 namespacing, which basically points to a file within a directory structure so different libraries can have the same class names without stepping on each other's toes.

Unless you declare the namespace for the SQLite class, it thinks the class lives in the same folder as your controller because that is where you called it from.

The SQLite3 class that is included in PHP has a namespace that starts with 'SQLite3', so by declaring that at the top, any reference made to that class will point to the proper script.

Answer (score 0):

It's a namespace issue. You are in the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace, which doesn't contain any `SQLite3` class.

Just add it to the list if `use` statements in the top of your file.

```
use SQLite3;
```

Now you shouldn't get that error anymore.

Read more in the manual: [Using namespaces: Aliasing/Importing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)